# Adding the same list to each row in a pandas DataFrame in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas DataFrame, `foo` for example:

```
>>> foo
   col1  col2
0     1     0
1     2     0
2     3     1
```

If you want to add a new column, all with the same value you can do

```
>>> foo['col3'] = 1
>>> foo
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     0     1
1     2     0     1
2     3     1     1
```

If you want to add another new column, all with specific values you can do

```
>>> foo['col4'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> foo
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     0     1     a
1     2     0     1     b
2     3     1     1     c
```

But what I want to do is add the same list to each row as new column. Something like

```
>>> myList = [True, False, False, True]
>>> foo['col5'] = {...something something something...}
>>> foo
   col1  col2  col3  col4                        col5
0     1     0     1     a  [True, False, False, True]
1     2     0     1     b  [True, False, False, True]
2     3     1     1     c  [True, False, False, True]
```

Using the previous method results in `ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')`. So at the moment, my `{...something something something...}` line is `foo['col5'] = [myList] * foo.shape[0]`. But I'm wondering, is there a better way?

Comment: Do you _really_ want references to the same list in each row? Because that's what your current solution does.

Comment: You can try `foo['col5'] = [myList]*len(foo)
`

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE Notice that suffers from a certain issue...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Not sure, what did I miss, is it performance or causes error?

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE Edited my answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a list comprehension.

```
v = [True, False, False, True]
df['col5'] = [v for _ in range(len(df))]
```

```
df
   col1  col2                        col5
0     1     0  [True, False, False, True]
1     2     0  [True, False, False, True]
2     3     1  [True, False, False, True]
```

---

You might be tempted to use

```
df['col5'] = [True, False, False, True] * len(df)
```

However, each record actually references the same list. Try this -

```
df.loc[0, 'col5'][0] = False
df

   col1  col2                         col5
0     1     0  [False, False, False, True]
1     2     0  [False, False, False, True]
2     3     1  [False, False, False, True]
```

You'll see the change is reflected across *all* sublists.

Comment: Great! I forgot about it :) +1